# How can I calculate leaves and nodes of a C 4.5 decision tree?

Tags: data-mining, cart

I have a given amount of attributes, for example 1024, and now want to calculate the amount of leaves and nodes C 4.5 produces (approximately).

Is there something like that for binary trees - a formula for example?

Comment: do you mean something specific for C4.5 or are you asking a general question on binary trees?

Comment: Special C4.5. I want to know a formula or way to estimate the leaves and nodes needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it very unlikely you will have a formula to calculate this, as it is highly dependent on intrinsic properties of the dataset you are working with. For example, a dataset which is easy to classify with only a few features would result in a small tree, but you would have no way of knowing that this is an easy problem in advance.

You can try looking through some papers that use C4.5 and see how many nodes/leafs they get, but I am not sure how useful that will be, unless you are using an extremely similar dataset.

Another approach you can try, depending on your needs, is to run C4.5 on multiple random samples of your data, and try to approximate from that how many nodes/leafs you will have in for the full dataset.